# How to update applications downloaded from the Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, updates, software-center

I recently downloaded Scala for Ubuntu through the Software Center, however when I check the version I downloaded was Scala 2.9.0, is there anyway I can upgrade/update this to Scala 2.10.1?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when ever Ubuntu/ Developer  prepared its upgrade for scala automatically it will flows to all Ubuntu users who are using scala.You no need to check for it manually. Its a automatic process. all you need to do is just wait for few days until its get ready.

If you want to upgrade it from source as mentioned by the above user means ,you will be able to use recent version as you want But **In future you won't receive any type of application updates,upgrades & bug fixes from Ubuntu**. 
you only have to do again manually.

you may ask me how many days have to wait ??
this is the [**Launchpad link of scala**](https://launchpad.net/scala) , there you can contact its maintainer and he will let you know when they will prepare it from 2.10.1.

so decision is up to you my friend.

If I am , I'd wait for Ubuntu update.

hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the latest release from the Scala website. Once again here are the commands I used to download and install the latest release of Scala on my machine:

```
wget http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.10.1.tgz
tar -xzf scala-2.10.1.tgz
sudo mv scala-2.10.1 /usr/share/scala
```

Comment: will it be automatically in my path?